# Conditionally Assign Value to Select Values Within a Variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a variable called STAFF. For certain STAFF members, I want to create a new variable and assign a value (28) to that variable for specific staff members. Then assign another value (14)for providers who are not in the initial group of provider who I want to assign the value of 28 to. And those in neither list to 0.

I have some generic code, but was curious how I can edit it so it includes only specific STAFF/not have write individual lines of code for each STAFF.

```
MASTER.loc[MASTER['STAFF'] == 'Manuel V.', 'PG_Hours'] = 28.8 
MASTER.loc[MASTER['STAFF'] == 'Dana M.', 'PG_Hours'] = 28.8 
MASTER.loc[MASTER['STAFF'] == 'Suzanne B.', 'PG_Hours'] = 28.8 
MASTER.loc[MASTER['STAFF'] == 'Tim G.', 'PG_Hours'] = 14
MASTER.loc[MASTER['STAFF'] =! '????', 'PG_Hours'] = 0

STAFF      PG_Hours 
Manuel V.     28
Tim G.        14
Dana M.       28
Suzanne B.    28
Chi N.        0
Missy S.      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.select` to assign multiple values based on multiple conditions and `.isin` for multiple names in one of the conditions:

```
MASTER['PG_Hours'] =  np.select([MASTER['STAFF'].isin(['Manuel V.', 'Dana M.', 'Suzanne B.']),
                                 MASTER['STAFF'] == 'Tim G.'], 
                                 [28.8, 14], 0)
```

`28.8` and `14` are the two results from the two conditions and zero is the alternative result. If you have more conditions you can adjust accordingly by listing the conditions in order and the results in order. The order of the list matters to correctly map condition to result.